# stop updates via group policy programmatically on windows 10 pro

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-10

I want to disable windows automatic updates using group policy. I tried disabling this `wuauserv` service that runs the auto-updates using:

```
sc config wuauserv start= disable
sc config bits start= disable
sc config DcomLaunch start= disable
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
net stop DcomLaunch
```

but that isn't what I am after. I want to disable the local group policy.

Another way I found was changing the registry value `DWORD DisableRootAutoUpdate = 1` but I could manage to make it work.

Comment: [Take a look at this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/disable-windows-10-update-in-the-registry-and-with-powershell/). Pretty sure that's what you want as group policy is usually just edited through the registry. Also, is there a reason you tagged powershell? Although compatible with Powershell, these commands are not native to Powershell

Comment: Why would you like to stop the computer from getting security updates?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thank you for your comment, do you mean that these functions are native for command prompt? I am trying to implement it in my electron installation using `nsis` and thought that i can do these using either cmd prompt or powershell.